# PHP-jQuery - How to populate dropdown with month name and set value to month number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list with month names, another one with days and another one with years and everything is fine except that I'm having issues setting the  to be the month number instead of the month name.

this is what I have.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function()
{
var minOffset = -70, maxOffset = -17;
var thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
var m_names = ['January', 'February', 'March','April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August', 'September', 'October','November', 'December'];
var month = 0;

for (var j = month; j <= 11; j++)
    {
        var months = m_names[ 0 + j].slice( 0, 3 );
        $('<option>', {value: months, text: months}).appendTo("#dob_month");
    }

for (var i = minOffset; i <= maxOffset; i++)
    { 
        var year = thisYear + i;
        $('<option>', {value: year, text: year}).appendTo("#dob_year");
    }
});
</script>
```

The days options are currently hard-coded in the form 1-31 (might need help with this to populate the correct amount of days for each month, February always being 29).

How can I set the option value to be for example 01 when January is picked?

I am open to any other suggestions besides this. Just please keep in mind that I will eventually concatenate year-month-day to check against a date in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change months to j+1 on value

like this

```
$('<option>', {value: j+1, text: months}).appendTo("#dob_month");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right then this should work:

`$('<option>', {value: j+1, text: months}).appendTo("#dob_month");`

Comment: Thank you Evan Taylor. I already accepted Davide's answer. You two had the same approach but I read his first.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var j = month; j <= 11; j++)
    {
        var months = m_names[ 0 + j].slice( 0, 3 );
        $('<option>', {value: j+1, text: months}).appendTo("#dob_month");
    }
```

Set the value of month to 1, 2, etc. This will be `j+1` as j starts from 0

Comment: Thank you. I'm only going to upvote your response but not accept it because Davide's response was first and are both the same and they work. I accepted his response since it was first.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want get, Try this:

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
    {
        var val;
        if (j<10)
            val="0"+j
        else
            val=j

        $('<option>', {value: val, text: m_names[j-1],slice(0,3)}).appendTo("#dob_month");
    }
```